# Adding and subtract inbetween row inputs and value equal to the first column next row using pandas

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

Assume I have a dataset with three inputs:

```
   x1   x2  x3  
0  a    b   c
1  d    e   f
2  g    h   i
3  j    k   l
4  m    n   o
5  p    q   r
6  s    t   u 
      :
      :
```

0,1,2,3 are times, x1, x2, x3 are inputs that are measured. So here x1 inputs are measured at every one hour. x2 and x3 will be measured at different time. What I need to do , I want write that what ever the measured in x1, x2, x3 it will add and subtract the values are equal to the x1 input next time value 
So here what I want to do is:

```
    x1   x2   x3   y
 0  a    b    c   a+b-c==d
 1  d    e    f   d+e+f==g
 2  g    h    i   g+h-i==j
 3  j    k    l   j+k-l==m
 4  m    n    o   m+n-o==p
 5  p    q    r   p+q-r==s
 6  s    t    u   s+t-u==v
         :
         :
```

I tried shift method and it didn't work for me what I want exactly. I tried another method and it worked, but didn't came as I want. Here I upload the code.

```
Code :
 data = pd.read_csv('data6.csv')
 i=0
 j=1
 while j < len(data):
   j=data['x1'][i] - data['x2'][i] + data['x3'][i] 
   i+=1 
   j!=i 
  print(j)
```

This is works , but it is just showing only one data

> 63

In my csv file this is second input value of x1 input.
I want to write this code contonously happened and read the value as I shown above.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So are you evaluating the equality of a+b-c and d for each sample? Meaning, you aim to save the boolean value? If so:

```py
import pandas as pd
#a sample dictionary
data = {'x1':[1,0,4,5,8,1], 
     'x2':[3,4,5,6,8,9],
     'x3':[4,5,1,-2,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) #converting the dictionary to dataframe
df['y'] = 0 #initializing the y column with 0, also you can initialize with FALSE boolean value
for i in range(len(df)-1): #iterating between all the rows of dataframe
    df['y'].iloc[i] = df['x1'].iloc[i] + df['x2'].iloc[i] - df['x3'].iloc[i] == df['x1'].iloc[i+1]
```

Note: for the last row, since the content of column y should be calculated based on the next row, the value cannot be calculated, that is why we have set `(len(df)-1)`.

Result:

```py
   x1  x2  x3      y
0   1   3   4   True
1   0   4   5  False
2   4   5   1  False
3   5   6  -2  False
4   8   8   4  False
5   1   9   5      0
```

---

**The problem with your code:**
First, you are not considering that subsequent row to calculate the accuracy of the expression $a+b-c ==d$
Second, if that print(j) is outside the loop, is it? then you are looping in the rows of data frame while j is less than data frame's length, So when the flow is out of this while, a single value j would be returned.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. I used your code , and it shows the same as you shown below. But I want to show the values not true or false, If I want to display value then how to chsnge the code?

Comment: yes j is in out loop, what about write in while loop ?

Comment: Here what I want is by adding or subtracting what ever the value is coming it will be equal to the x1 column next value (!=)

Comment: But the thing that you were saving into column **y** is a boolean value (a+b-c==d) you are comparing the equality of (a+b-c) and (d). So this is not a value.

So, in my example, would y be 0,4,5,8,1 at the end?

Comment: If so you just need to write:
```python
df['y'].iloc[i] = df['x1'].iloc[i+1]
```
in the last line of the code.

Comment: Actually I am going to develop neural network model to predict future x1 value. So this mathematical equation will affect to predict next value of x1 . So that's why I am trying to build the combination inbetween these numerical value  that I have .

Comment: Wooww it worked . Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :)